# How to check if a char contains a specific letter

Tags: c++, struct, char, structure, c-strings

I'm trying to produce code that will check how many "A", "C", "G", and "T" characters a char contains. But I'm a little unsure how to go about doing this.. because as far as I know there aren't any operators like .contains() to check with.

The desired output would be something like:

```
"The char contains (variable amount) of letter A's"
```

In my code I have this right now:

```
DNAnt countDNAnt(char strand)
{
    DNAnt DNA;

    if (isupper(strand) == "A")
    {
        DNA.adenine++;
    }
    else if (isupper(strand) == "C")
    {
        DNA.cytosine++;
    }
    else if (isupper(strand) == "G")
    {
        DNA.guanine++;
    }
    else if (isupper(strand) == "T")
    {
        DNA.thymine++;
    }
}
```

DNAnt is a structure that has the desired variables that I'm checking for (the A's, C's, G's and T's). And I'm trying to basically add to the amount of each whenever I find it inside of the char.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Last time I checked, a `char` is big enough for exactly one `char`. No more, nor less.

Comment: You mean like, a char would only contain a character like "A"? If that's how char's work then I think I need to change my logic a little bit :P

Comment: Yes, that's what a `char` is. One character. No more, no less.

Comment: You mean `toupper`, not `isupper`.

Comment: `int a_count = std::count_if( str.begin(), str.end(), [](char c) { return c == 'a' | c == 'A'; } );`

Comment: BTW, single quotes for single letters, double quotes for 2 or more letters.  So your statement should be `"if (isupper(strand) == 'A')"`.  BTW, you can use a `switch` with characters; convert `strand` to uppercase, then use `switch`.

Comment: @paddy depends if his function needs to be case sensitive. Otherwise I would agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lot of problems with the posted code, the biggest of which is a new `DNAnt` is created and returned every time. This will make the counting way more complicated than is necessary because now you have to count `DNAnts`. Instead of fixing this code, here's a really simple and stupid different way to do this:

```
std::map<char,int> DNACount;
```

creates an object that binds a character to a number.

```
DNACount[toupper(strand)]++;
```

If there isn't one already, this creates a character/number pairing for the character `strand` and sets the number to zero. Then the number paired with `strand` is increased by one.

So all you have to do is read through the sequence something like

```
std::map<char,int> DNACount;
for (char nucleotide:strand)// where strand is a string of nucleotide characters
{
    DNACount[toupper(nucleotide)]++;
}
std::cout << "A count = " << DNACount['A'] << '\n';
std::cout << "C count = " << DNACount['C'] << '\n';
....
```

[Documentation for `std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)