# Counting Frequency of Characters in a string C++

Tags: c++, char, counting

I'm trying to count the frequency of letters in a string input. I'm having some trouble and I don't exactly know what I'm doing incorrectly. I'm getting weird outputs, like smiley faces. I want my code to do something like this, if the string is "abcdc" 
a - 1
b - 1
c - 2
d - 1

```
      #include <iostream>
using namespace std;




class moose
{
    char inputbuffer[132];
    char countbuffer[122];
    long count;
    short index = 0;
public:
    char charcount();
    char charinput();
    char initialize();

};

int main()
{
    moose obj;
    obj.initialize();
    obj.charinput();
    obj.charcount();
    system("pause");

}


char moose::initialize()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 122; i++)
        countbuffer[i] = 0;
    return 0;

}

char moose::charinput()
{
    cout << "Enter your text and I'll read your characters" << endl;
    cin.getline(inputbuffer, 132);
    cin.gcount();
    count = cin.gcount();
    count--;
    return 0;
}

char moose::charcount()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (inputbuffer[i] >= 'a' & inputbuffer[i] <= 'z') {
            index = inputbuffer[i];
            countbuffer[index]++;

        }
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            cout << inputbuffer[i] << " - " << countbuffer[index] << endl;
        }
    }




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: off topic: Just answered a similar question. The approach may be of use. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40967365/4581301

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues with the code:

1. The `moose::charinput()` method contains extra call to `gcount()`. You need only this statement: `count = cin.gcount();`. The `count--;` should not be there, too.
2. The condition inside `moose::charcount()` has to be

   ```
   if (inputbuffer[i] >= 'a' && inputbuffer[i] <= 'z')
   ```
3. The `moose::charcount()` should have two distinct loops:

   ```
       char moose::charcount()
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
           {
               if (inputbuffer[i] >= 'a' && inputbuffer[i] <= 'z') {
                   index = inputbuffer[i];
                   countbuffer[index]++;
               }
           }
           for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
           {
               cout << inputbuffer[i] << " - " << countbuffer[inputbuffer[i]] << endl;
           }   
           return 0;
       }
   ```
4. `countbuffer` has to be declared is `int` to be printed properly

Comment: ^^ This is no different from my original code. It isn't quite doing what I want. if for example I type in "aaaaaa" it will ouput a-1 a-2 a-3 a-4 a-5 ect, I am trying to just output a-6. thanks for the help though

Comment: If this is your intention, you array with counters should be `counter[26]`, you should count the characters like`counter[inputbuffer[i] - 'a']` and print like `cout << (char)('a' + i) << " - " << count[i] << endl;` By the way, your code does not count uppercase symbols, Don't you need them?

Comment: Yes I will need them, as well as counting 0-9. I was trying to get my brain wrapped up on how I would output my lowercase arrays first. I figure to count upper and numbers, I will create two more For Loops of logic. I'm not quite sure what you mean with the counter[26] and counter[inputbuffer[i] - 'a'] but I'm getting some ideas, again appreciate the guidance!

Comment: There are 26 characters from 'a' to 'z'. So you need only 26 numbers to count the lower case characters. The same applies to printing the results.